# Remove placehoder input file name when click on "X" button, and display default input field text

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click on [image] upload icon , I can choose file for attachment, and then I get [image] with "X" remove attachment button (@extend .icon-cross; in sass). When I click on X remove attachment button, I want to achieve that return default input filed text (Upload field) instead of attached file name (in this case for example asdf.txt)

```js
export default function File(sandbox, hub) {

  'use strict';


  let $file = $('input.input-file-hidden');

  /**
   * onChange event handler
   * @function onChange
   * @private
   */
  function onChange() {
    let $placeholder = $('span.input-file-placeholder', $(this).closest('div.input-file'));
    $placeholder.text(
      $(this)[0].files[0].name);
    $placeholder.parent().addClass('filled');
  }


  return {
    /**
     * initialize File
     */
    init() {
      $file.on('change', onChange);
      hub.on('inputfile:init', components => {
        components.forEach(function(component) {
          $(component).find('input.input-file-hidden').on('change', onChange);
        });
      });
    }
  }
}
```

```css
&.filled {
  .input-file-button .icon {
    position: relative;
    top: -4px;
    left: -2px;
    font-size: 15px;
    @extend .icon-cross;
    @include breakpoint(phone) {
      font-size: 24px;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2 no-gutter-right">
  <div class="form-elements-label">Normal</div>
  <div class="input-file input-file--with-icon">
    <label class="text-hide" for="f405">Upload field<sup>*</sup></label>
    <input class="input-file-hidden" type="file" required data-max-size="10485760" data-max-size-error-text="* File size is too large">
    <input class="input-file-elem" type="text" id="f405">
    <span class="input-file-placeholder">Upload field<sup>*</sup></span>
    <span class="input-file-bg">input background</span>
    <span class="input-file-button"><span class="icon icon-download"></span></span>
    <div class="input-file-additional-info text-right">
      <span class="additional-info-text">* JPG, PNG (max 10Mb)</span>
      <span class="error-text"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I was try so far, in JS add (with .val(' ') on click X,  I changed value from "file name, asdf.txt" to "No file chosen"
as a title on hover over input field) but I need to change input field name to  default input field text "Upload field" :

```
let $remove = $('.input-file input-file--with-icon.filled .icon-download');
remove.on("click", function () {
        $placeholder.val('');
    });
```

Comment: I think you need to call `$('.input-file').val('');` in your `remove` function, the placeholder should then change automatically. Also, your jQuery selector is wrong, you're missing a dot (.) for the `input-file--with-icon` class: `$('.input-file.input-file--with-icon')`.

Comment: unfortunately, does not work because does not remove input file name again, but input file value from name asdf.txt to No file chosen

Answer (score 0):

You just need to reset the value of the file input field then the placeholder should update accordingly.

`$('.input-file-hidden').val('');`

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined...   $remove.on("click", function () {
            $('.input-file-hidden').val('');
        });
    }
does not remove input file name again, but value from name to No file chosen. Can you help me?

Comment: That error means you're trying to access the name of something that does not exist. 

However for the 'No file chosen' part, you need to reset it manually by adding `$('.input-file-placeholder').html('Upload field<sup>*</sup>')` too, in your remove block.

Comment: Ok, how to get rid of that error . Does not work anything because I have that error

Comment: Replace `$placeholder.text($(this)[0].files[0].name);` with `if($(this)[0].files.length>0){$placeholder.text( $(this)[0].files[0].name);}`

Comment: Great, thank you Peter, there are no more error message... If you can help me, if no, never mind. Situation is - when I click on remove X button, input file name does not disappear, but open box to chose file again (like upload). I think problem is with click event , because when I set up alert("Click") in $remove.on("click", function () {
            $placeholder.html('Upload field<sup>*</sup>')
        }); , nothing happens, there are no alert message

Comment: Set up a `jsfiddle` with what you have now. I'll correct it there for you.

Comment: this is part of remove click button , http://prntscr.com/ekzl4y ....... let $remove = $('.input-file .input-file--with-icon.filled .icon-download'); ......what's wrong here, so doent trigger click event

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, works like a charm, @Peter help me partly with his suggestion

```js
function onChange() {
  let $placeholder = $('span.input-file-placeholder', $(this).closest('div.input-file'));

  if ($(this)[0].files.length > 0) {
    $placeholder.text($(this)[0].files[0].name)
  }

  $placeholder.parent().addClass('filled');

  let $remove = $('.input-file.input-file--with-icon.filled .input-file-button .icon.icon-download');

  $remove.on('click', function() {
    $placeholder.html('Upload field<sup>*</sup>');
    $file.val('');
    $placeholder.parent().removeClass('filled');
  });
}
```